# Running averages on unique values within the same column

Tags: excel

Let me preface this by saying that I'm pretty bad with excel. Here goes:

I'm working with a rather large dataset.

The basic table heading layout is as follows:

```
School    | StudentID   | BodyMassIndex
Appleton   11111111       22 
Appleton   222222222      21 
Madison    111111         30 
Madison    3333333        19
```

And so on with 130+ schools and up to 50 rows per school

Basically what I'm trying to do is derive school wide averages,ranges, medians etc. for each unique school and create a new table with each school and it's statistical summary data

Is there any way to do this without painstakingly running the average command on the data for each school individually?

Thanks and let me know if I can provide any additional helpful information!

Comment: Create a unique list of schools in another sheet and use `AVERAGEIF` or `AVERAGEIFS`.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain the steps a little better? I'm new to this...So basically create a column with the 130 schools in a new sheet and then the average if will let me reference the other sheet?

Comment: Exactly. Or as the answer below said, use a Pivot Table, which is a quick and powerful (albeit slightly inflexible) approach. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at pivot tables. Which is the answer to 95% of data analysis related excel questions on stack overflow.

You can very easily make something that looks like this:

[image: 1]

Tutorials abound. Just google it:

http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/datamanagementinexcel/tp/090929-excel-pivot-table-tutorial-hub.htm

Comment: If you really want to get "fancy" you can learn about pivot-charts - which is the same concept - in addition they enable the relatively easy automatic creation of charts.

Comment: I definatly would not say pivot tables are the answer to 95% of data analysis related excel questions on stack overflow. But maybe 95% of data analysis related excel questions. Either way +1 simple basic and working solution.